# How to disable auto commit in kafka using mule 4

Tags: apache-kafka, mulesoft, mule4, seek, autocommit

I am using a kafka publish connector, which is publishing the payload supplied through postman. Now, there is kafka listener which listens to the messages in that topic (which has only 1 partition). In the same kafka listener flow there is a seek operation which is trying to seek a value for the particular offset. And as it is getting auto committed, the seek is not fetching the the offset value we are providing. Need your valuable suggestions to make the seek operator seek values from previous offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Set the acknowledgement mode to MANUAL in the Kafka connector configuration and ensure to have a [Commit operation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/kafka-connector/4.6/kafka-connector-reference#consumer-operations) when it ends correctly.